# API returns HTML response after API protection using custom guard and passport

Tags: laravel, api, rest, laravel-passport, laravel-middleware

I hope you're doing well, I just need some help with my problem, been stuck at it for a while now and I cannot figure out a work around. I implemented another login for the admin in my project and I use a custom guard and custom middleware for it. This works properly without any problem. The problem started when I try to protect the API routes using passport. For the users which uses the auth:api as the API middleware, everything works fine. But in my custom guard, it returns an HTML response(console.log says it returns HTML but it does not output anything in the UI) instead of json. If I remove the route protection it would work again as intended. I hope you can help me with this one. Thank you!

I am using Laravel Passport for the API protection.

This is how it looks like without the API route protection(This is how it should be).
[image]

This is how it looks like with the route protection
[image]

This is what console.log returns with route protection. Without it, it returns the response from the first picture.

[image]

Here's my code below

**AdminMiddleware**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('admin.login');
        }
    }
```

**Kernel.php**

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth.admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
 ];
```

**config/auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'adminApi' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'hash' => false,
    ]
],
```

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.admin:adminApi']], function(){
    Route::get('/fetch-announcements', [AnnouncementController::class, 'showAnnouncement']);
    Route::post('/store-announcements',[AnnouncementController::class, 'storeAnnouncement']);
});
```

**Models/Admin.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, HasApiTokens;
    protected $fillable =[
        'email',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];
    
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**Get Request**

```
await axios.get('/api/fetch-announcements', {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                }
            })
                .then(response => {
                    this.announcements = response.data
                    console.log(this.announcements)
                })
                .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

**EDIT** The API returns a 302 code

Comment: In your middleware, try to replace return redirect()->route('admin.login'); as return response()->json()

Comment: @AndreHaykal HI! Thanks for the reply. The middleware is being used only to redirect whenever someone is not authenticated. However, here is my Controller for the announcements

Comment: return new AnnouncementResource(Announcement::latest()->take(3)->get());

Comment: Your request doesn't include the Authorization key try adding `Authorization: 'Bearer ' + your passport_token` to the axios header

Comment: @Abdusalammohamed Hi I also did try this. Does not work though, same problem still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API return html response because the middleware that you created before, when the auth check is failing, it will redirect you to admin login page.

First, you should check the API that you called from axios is include the token or not, if not, it will run the else statement.

Next, your middleware will only return redirect page (302) when the auth guard check failed, either in web or api. If you want your API return a json, you may change your middleware just like below code, dont forget add header 'Accept': 'application/json' on your request.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            return response()->json([
                "error" => true,
                "message" => "Unauthenticated"
            ], 403);
        }else{
            return redirect()->route("cart.index");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I tried your code, and yes it does actually run the else statement and gives back an error 403. So most probably this is because the request does not have a token? Just to clarify, you mean the token created by Laravel passport? I'm sorry I'm new to Laravel Passport and securing API routes hence this project as a practice. I checked my axios request and the only token in there is the X-XSRF-TOKEN

Comment: Yes, the token from passport. The token should be included in your request when you accessing route with auth middleware, put it on the headers request "Authorization : Bearer tokenxxxxx". You can try your API by using postman, if in postman no error appeared, go check on your front end code.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply. Took a long break from coding but you were right. It was the token that was missing. Postman gives me the proper result! I did however had to change up some things to make it work. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just send a header for the request as `Accept: application/json`.

So you will get the same as JSON.

Comment: hi, thanks for answering! I did add it in after seeing your comment. However, it still returns the same response. Please see the post again, I added my get request. I cannot format it properly here in the comments

Comment: Instead test the api in postman.